# The 'Box' object has no attribute 'spaces'

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to implement a game class where you have to stay in the 49-51 number range as long as possible. The state space is given by a range from 0 to 100, the initial state is the number 47 or the number 53 (chosen randomly), and you can change the state of the environment by three actions - adding 0, adding 1 or adding -1. Also, after each action there is a random addition of 1 or -1

I need to choose an algorithm from the baseline3 library and train it. I train the PPO algorithm, but I get the following error:
The 'Box' object has no attribute 'spaces'.
Box has no 'spaces' attribute, what could be the problem?

```
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
import random
from gym import Env
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box


class CustomEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = Box(low=np.array([0]), high=np.array([100]))
        self.state = 50 +- random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.length = 120

    def step(self, action):
        self.state += action-1
        self.length -= 1
    
        if self.state >= 49 and self.state <= 51:
            reward = 1
        else:
            reward = -1
        
        if self.length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        
        self.state += random.randint(-1, 1)
    
        return self.state, reward, done, {}

    def reset(self):
        self.state = 50 +- random.randint(-3, 3)
        self.length = 120
    
env = CustomEnv()
model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env)
model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [148], in <cell line: 41>()
     38         self.length = 120
     40 env = CustomEnv()
---> 41 model = PPO("MultiInputPolicy", env)
     42 model.learn(total_timesteps=20000)

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py:162, in PPO.__init__(self, policy, env, learning_rate, n_steps, batch_size, n_epochs, gamma, gae_lambda, clip_range, clip_range_vf, normalize_advantage, ent_coef, vf_coef, max_grad_norm, use_sde, sde_sample_freq, target_kl, tensorboard_log, create_eval_env, policy_kwargs, verbose, seed, device, _init_setup_model)
    159 self.target_kl = target_kl
    161 if _init_setup_model:
--> 162     self._setup_model()

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\ppo\ppo.py:165, in PPO._setup_model(self)
    164 def _setup_model(self) -> None:
--> 165     super()._setup_model()
    167     # Initialize schedules for policy/value clipping
    168     self.clip_range = get_schedule_fn(self.clip_range)

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\on_policy_algorithm.py:117, in OnPolicyAlgorithm._setup_model(self)
    106 buffer_cls = DictRolloutBuffer if isinstance(self.observation_space, gym.spaces.Dict) else RolloutBuffer
    108 self.rollout_buffer = buffer_cls(
    109     self.n_steps,
    110     self.observation_space,
   (...)
    115     n_envs=self.n_envs,
    116 )
--> 117 self.policy = self.policy_class(  # pytype:disable=not-instantiable
    118     self.observation_space,
    119     self.action_space,
    120     self.lr_schedule,
    121     use_sde=self.use_sde,
    122     **self.policy_kwargs  # pytype:disable=not-instantiable
    123 )
    124 self.policy = self.policy.to(self.device)

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py:802, in MultiInputActorCriticPolicy.__init__(self, observation_space, action_space, lr_schedule, net_arch, activation_fn, ortho_init, use_sde, log_std_init, full_std, sde_net_arch, use_expln, squash_output, features_extractor_class, features_extractor_kwargs, normalize_images, optimizer_class, optimizer_kwargs)
    782 def __init__(
    783     self,
    784     observation_space: gym.spaces.Dict,
   (...)
    800     optimizer_kwargs: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None,
    801 ):
--> 802     super().__init__(
    803         observation_space,
    804         action_space,
    805         lr_schedule,
    806         net_arch,
    807         activation_fn,
    808         ortho_init,
    809         use_sde,
    810         log_std_init,
    811         full_std,
    812         sde_net_arch,
    813         use_expln,
    814         squash_output,
    815         features_extractor_class,
    816         features_extractor_kwargs,
    817         normalize_images,
    818         optimizer_class,
    819         optimizer_kwargs,
    820     )

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\policies.py:461, in ActorCriticPolicy.__init__(self, observation_space, action_space, lr_schedule, net_arch, activation_fn, ortho_init, use_sde, log_std_init, full_std, sde_net_arch, use_expln, squash_output, features_extractor_class, features_extractor_kwargs, normalize_images, optimizer_class, optimizer_kwargs)
    458 self.activation_fn = activation_fn
    459 self.ortho_init = ortho_init
--> 461 self.features_extractor = features_extractor_class(self.observation_space, **self.features_extractor_kwargs)
    462 self.features_dim = self.features_extractor.features_dim
    464 self.normalize_images = normalize_images

File E:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\stable_baselines3\common\torch_layers.py:258, in CombinedExtractor.__init__(self, observation_space, cnn_output_dim)
    255 extractors = {}
    257 total_concat_size = 0
--> 258 for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():
    259     if is_image_space(subspace):
    260         extractors[key] = NatureCNN(subspace, features_dim=cnn_output_dim)

AttributeError: 'Box' object has no attribute 'spaces'
```

Comment: `Box` doesn't have variable `space` but `low` and `high`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not familiar with gym; but, your ```CustomEnv``` is a descendant class of ```Env```; but you don't actually do a ```super(CustomEnv, self).__init__()``` or ```CustomEnv.__init__(self)```.   I don't know if this is your problem though.

Comment: error shows line `for key, subspace in observation_space.spaces.items():` and I found that `spaces.Dict()` uses `spaces.items()` - and maybe `PPO` needs something like this. And next line `if is_image_space(subspace):` may suggest it may need images.

Comment: if I use `self.observation_space = Dict({'value':Box(...)})` then it doesn't show this error. But it shows other errors. It may need bigger changes in code. OR maybe `PPO` is not good idea for this task.